# Задача с морковью на Pacsal

Tags: pascal

В общем так. Как я ранее упоминал задачу с ящиками вот ее все условие. Кто-то со склада украл ящики. Каждый ящик был со счетчиком, показывающий  количество морковок. Надо найти ящик с наименьшим содержанием моркови. К примеру, было украдено 2 ящика: в 1 было 5 морковок, а во втором 3. Загвоздка в том, что ящики могут увеличиваться. `N (ящики) -  (2 ≤ N ≤ 2*106)`. Ранее мне подсказали, что нужно делать динамический массив (большое спасибо).

```
Type a = array of Integer;

Var i,n: Integer;

 b : a;

Begin

{{Дело в том что данные мы получаем из input.txt}}

Readln(n);

Setlength(b,n);

for i:=0 to n-1 do

begin

{{Вот что делать с этим кодом? Вводится ВСЕ с input'а.}}

Write("Введите количество морковок в ящике №"+(i+1)+":");

Readln(a);

b[i] = a;

end;
```

Что тут делать, я не пойму. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тогда уж так

```
begin
clrscr;
   assign (fl, 'input.txt');
    while not Eof(fl) do // пока не достигнут конец файла
       begin
        readln (fl,str);
        // тут делать нужные действия.
       end;
close(fl);
```